# Knockout web application is overloading IE8. Suggestions?

Tags: knockout.js, memory-leaks, internet-explorer-8, knockout-projections

I have a pretty robust web application implementing the latest Knockout.js binding framework. Many of my observables are computed arrays and there are many computed aggregate totals. The page renderings are as optimized as I could get them, using a variety of different templating methods to display the various groupings of objects.

Everything is working great in the latest browsers, but not in IE8/10.

This issues boils down to a memory consumption problem.

It makes IE use 600MB of memory - just loading it. When we switch views (new URL's entirely). There are moments when memory doesn't get released, and it just climbs and climbs until it runs out. Just switching back and forth a few times between these pages, I can make IE use 2GB easily, and this is with IE10 as well. The problem is only worse in IE8.

The code base is simply too large to publish as examples. If anyone has had any experiences in the past with this I'd love to hear more about how you went about 'fixing' some of the issues and if there are certain usages which I need to avoid for the sake of compatibility.

I am using some mapping features of the new Projections library in addition to common mapping functions and knockout utilities.

Thanks for reading and any of your thoughts.

Comment: Can a lot of the calculations, aggregations whatever not been done server side?

Comment: I've definitely thought of doing that. There are some totals we could shift over to the server, but it really shouldn't be necessary. The performance on later browsers is great. My hope is to be able to optimize any 'leaky' knockout features without having to add to the complexity that we're already leaning on the server to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

Try to ensure that you are disposing of any subscriptions that become invalid

Comment: The app is simply too much to bear upon the shoulders of the past...farewell IE8...clients are happily switching to 'other' shiny metallic-plated options...we're okay with that

Comment: Even better you can use the knockout.es5 plugin now, and clean up your models

Comment: ahhh, don't want that. i like having control over what's observed and what's not...models are as trimmed down as they're going to get...I was hoping to have gained something from the 'new' projections library, but that couldn't handle the hits either...only use it in special cases now